# What is the limit of HABTM relations in MongoDB / MongoId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

When using a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` with MongoId](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#has-and-belongs-to-many), like:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_teams
end
```

Both models get a new field which holds the ids of the related objects:

```
user.user_team_ids = [ ... ]
```

My Question: With the [limitations of documents, which is 16MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size), is it correct to assume the limit is around 450.000 relations per object?

My absolute naive way of getting this number is:

```
16 MB / 37 byte per ID = 432.432 ID
```

*(37 byte is the length of an `JSON` string of an `BSON::ObjectId`)*

This is not about if you should use relations with MongoDB or not - it's more a question to understand the implications of using them.

Comment: Seems reasonable and easy to confirm as well by testing.

Comment: Right. Got my daily facepalm earlier than expected. Will try that today.